# how to get sessionId element from cookie

Tags: java, android, cookies, android-webview, session-variables

I am doing a webview project in android java in cordova framework .The session id is sent as cookie from the server when user logs in.I need the session id for maintaining the session. I am getting cookie as

```
ASP.NET_Session_Id=123345; yourAuthCookie=6415176A0448E891D99DAA57BBB7FC77785AD0A3F2BCBAF660957E1CE4A7C3D47E5FDF1DDA522FBC1306C96A50029E088805CC1ECC223CE0B4A29286327907779F5FFEBD8F6AA8B2CE685579667BB29D4CBC50C1EEA
```

I just want session id . How can i get just the session id from cookie?

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here... What language are you using? Is it raw or are you using some framework? What is the purpose? etc. This will make everything easy to understand for the people that try to answer you! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found an answer,

```
public String cookieElement(String Url,String CookieName){
    String CookieValue = null;

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(Url);
    String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
    for (String ar1 : temp ){
        if(ar1.contains(CookieName)){
            String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
            CookieValue = temp1[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return CookieValue;
}
```

the function can be called as

`String sessionid = cookieElement("https://www.example.com/","ASP.NET_Session_Id");`